# Linux error while booting and turning off

Tags: error-handling

Recently I've started seeing these errors in command line:

1. This one shows before Dell logo appears when I start laptop.

```
[0.209754] x86/cpu: SGX disabled by BIOS.
/devnvme0n1p2: clean, 989353/15597568 files, 42128799/62383360 blocks
[4.936267] mtd device must be supplied (device name is empty)
[7.206780] nvidia-gpu 0000:01:00 i2c timeout error e0000000
[7.208217] ucsi_ccg 0-0008: i2c_transfer failed -110
[7.208237] ucsi_ccg 0-0008: ucsi_ccg_init failed -110
[7.674289] mtd device must be supplied (device name is empty)
```

2. When I turn off or restart laptop, this one shows up and blocks further execution.

```
[OK] Stopped Permit User Sessions.
[OK] Stopped target User and Group Name Lookups.
[OK] Stopped target Remote File Systems.
[OK] Started Show Plymouth File Off Screen.
[ ***] A stop job is running for OPSWAT CLient for Linus (imin 5s / 1min 30c)
```

What are these errors and how can I resolve them?

My battery is in bad condition. Could it be the cause of these problems?

Comment: Please read the info on this site https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask The first set of errors is common on some machines right now and can be ignored unless they stop the machine for running the OS. As for the second set, are you simply using the power button or shutting the machine down properly? None of these errors have anything to do with a bad battery.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: I use latest version 22.04.1. But these problems appeared in last version too. First one never happened before, it started to show only a couple of months ago. And second one appears in every situation, on restart or on turn off.

Comment: You can ignore these messages.